# where the global and local variables are stored in memory in C

Tags: c, embedded

I work with the Aurix MUC, I tried to read the contents of the memory after the execution of a program, to see what he wrote in the memoir

I noticed that when I use a global variable in a function, the new value of this global variable after processing in the function, is not written in memory.

Here is an example:

```
int a = 100;

void plus (int a)

{

 a = a + 17;

}

int main (void)

{

 plus(a);

 return 0;

}
```

when I display the contents of the memory I find the value 100 of a

and I do not find the new value of a which is normally 117.

I tried to declare the variable a as volatile, but it does not change anything

on the other hand if I do the calculation directly in the main like this

```
int a = 100;

int main (void)

{

 a = a + 17

 return 0;

}
```

like that I find the value 117 in the memory.

so I need to understand where are there save variables values used in the call functions?

and why the new variable of a is not written in memory,

and why the variables declared in local are not also written in the memory?

Comment: `void plus (int a)` - `a` is a local variable inside `plus`.

Comment: To expand on what @KamilCuk said, when you call a function with a parameter like that you're passing a copy of that variable, not the original. Change the parameter to a new name like `b`, and use `a = b + 17;` and it will change the global variable.

Comment: http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/CMST302/study_guide/topic4/storage_class.html

Comment: I can't be bothered to find a duplicate. Simply study functions and scopes in a beginner-level C programming book.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
int a = 100;

void plus(int a)
{   
    a = a + 17;
}
```

The `int a` in `void plus(int a)` declares a new instance of `a` that *hides* the previous `a`. Then, in `a = a + 17;`, this new instance of `a` is used. To have `plus` change the `a` declared outside the function, use:

```
int a = 100;

void plus(void)
{
    a = a + 17;
}
```

Also, in `main`, change `plus(a);` to `plus();`.

In C, each identifier has a *scope*, where is where in the source code is visible. A declaration outside of any function has *file scope*, meaning the identifiers declared are visible throughout the file (technically a *translation unit*). In a function definition, a declaration of a parameter has *block scope* associated with the function—it is visible only within the function.

Because the `int a = 100;` has file scope, you do not need to redeclare it in `plus` in order to use it—it is visible inside the function, so you can just use it without a new declaration.